# How the executing thread gets terminated when Response.Redirect("url",true) is used.?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How the executing thread gets terminated when Response.Redirect("url",true) is used.?

And how Does the Compiler know by this Boolean value that the thread should pe executed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) has the following to say about Response.Redirect and its boolean parameter:

> When you use this method in a page handler to terminate a request for one page and start a new request for another page, set endResponse to **false** and then call the CompleteRequest method. **If you specify true for the endResponse parameter, this method calls the [End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) method for the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception when it completes** [Emphasis mine]. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web application performance, which is why passing **false** for the endResponse parameter is recommended. For more information, see the End method.

Also notice that it's not the compiler that knows what should be done. It's just the way the `Redirect` method is implemented. More details in the link provided.